ordering of conjugacy classes in MAGMA
I have a family of finite groups, and I want to use the compute algebra system MAGMA to evaluate certain characters of these groups at specific conjugacy classes.  The CharacterTable commmand returns the character table of each group based on an ordering of the conjugacy classes of the group.  The ConjugacyClasses commands separately returns a complete list of conjugacy classes of the group.
Question:  Are these two lists of conjugacy classes the same?
More generally, if the output of two MAGMA commands contain the same information in the form of a list, do these two lists always have the same ordering (up to whatever identification as is appropriate in the given situation)?
For the conjugacy class question above, I checked a few case and the two lists are indeed the same.  I also know that some MAGMA commands involve randomization, so I want to double check but I don't know where to look for confirmation.  Many thanks for your help!

The answer to the more general question is no, there is no reason to assume two lists generated by different intrinsics will be in the same order. There is no reason to assume that even a fixed intrinsic will return the information in the same order every time. (For the specific case of the ConjugacyClasses/CharacterTable commands, I don't know.)
